# Pass typedefed function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, compiler-errors

I have two functions with the same signature and i defined a function pointer for them. Additionally, i typedefed the mentioned function pointer to simplify use of it. The code is like:

```
int add(int first_op, int second_op)
{
    return first_op + second_op;
}

int subtract(int first_op, int second_op)
{
    return first_op - second_op;
}

typedef int (*functionPtr)(int, int);

int do_math(functionPtr, int first, int second){
    return functionPtr(first, second);
}

main() {
    int a=3, b=2;
    functionPtr f = &add;
    printf("Result of add = %d\n", f(a,b));

    f = &subtract;
    printf("Result of subtract = %d\n", f(a,b));
}
```

I get two errors for method **do_math** as follows:

> In function ‘do_math’: error: parameter name omitted
>    int do_math(functionPtr, int first, int second){
>
> error: expected expression before ‘functionPtr’
>     return functionPtr(first, second);

What i have done wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`functionPtr` is a type. Parameters must also have a name:

```
int do_math(functionPtr function, int first, int second){
    return function(first, second);
}
```